# Having trouble understanding how "readdir.c" works in the Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I've heard `filldir()`/`filldir64()` lets the kernel specify the "dirent" (directory entry) layout depending on the binary type. Why do differing binary types matter?

I am also confused about dir_context, I assume `filldir64()` can be defined by other filesystems and implemented differently? So is that why there is an actor member?

`filldir64()`: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/readdir.c#L307

`dir_context`: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1776

Comment: Look at the declaration of the `ino` parameter in the two versions of the function. In `filldir` it's `int`, in `filldir64` it's `u64`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is to run old binaries. The ABI of the `readdir()` system call has changed a few times. The way this works is each system call number calls a different function. There's a common implementation of the filldir loop that dispatches to the filesystem-specific calls to read directory entires, and again dispatches to the appropriate `filldir()` implementation.

`dir_context` is defined by the specific implementation of `filldir()` to retain some state between calls. Desipite being written in C, the filesystem is object-oriented code. When you see stuff like this, start thinking virtual method dispatch, becasue effectively that's what it is. But since it's done in C, the `this` pointer has to be passed manually as the first argument.

Comment: So `filldir64()` fills the directory up and requires different implementations to handle older binaries? Could you tell me a little bit about `iterate_dir()` and whatever `vfs_readdir()` was? Where can I find more information on how files are listed by the kernel, in relation to this VFS abstraction layer?